# Is it safe to convert vector address to native pointer?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to pass the vector address to pointer before passing it to some external API call, is it safe to do so? The underlying question is that are the elements in vector ensured to be consecutive in memory?

```
std::vector<Type> vT;
Type* p = (Type*)&vT[0];
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, and you don't even need to cast it.

Comment: Thanks, I need to do the cast since native pointer type is required by the API to call.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is that `&vT[0]` is already the native pointer type you are looking for, without the need to cast.

Comment: @Thomson: You don't need to cast. Even if you did you should not be using the C-cast.

Comment: is this returning a copy or reference?

Comment: It's returning a pointer, but in terms of your question, it's returning a "reference", meaning that it's not copying anything.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `&v[0]` is safe to do and yes, the elements are contiguous in memory. I personally would use [`v.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), though, since that conveys the idea a lot better (you want to get the internal array, the *data*, after all).

Comment: I don't agree that data() conveys the intention `better`. Its not worse either though. But the idiom of taking the address of the first elements has become quite well known.

Comment: .. and 100% compatible with the C equivalent if he happens to ever swap out the `std::vector` out for a C array of the native type: `Type vT[MAX_ARRAY_ELEMS], *pVT = vT; Type *p1 = &vT[0]; Type *p2 = &pvT[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the vector is non-empty before you do so.

`Type *p = ( vT.empty() ? NULL : &vT[0] );`

Or as Xeo noted, the new library spec allows for `.data()` member function that does the same thing (may not be available in your implementation).

Comment: calculating the address one-past-the-end should be valid also... of course it may not be a suitable value to pass to any function

Comment: @Ben: Accessing `v[0]` if `v` is empty is UB, doesn't matter if you only take it's address right away.